# Proteins with alpha helices alone and beta sheets alone?

Tags: proteins, pdb

I would like to see some examples of proteins with PDB ID so that I can download and see them in [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) software. I need some proteins with alpha helix only and proteins with beta sheets alone.

Answer (score 5):

You may consider taking a look at the [SCOP](http://scop.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/scop/index.html) structural classification of proteins to check [all beta proteins](http://scop.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/scop/data/scop.b.c.html) and [all alpha proteins](http://scop.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/scop/data/scop.b.b.html). As per specific examples and though not belonging to the SCOP classes mentioned above, [Porin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porin_(protein)) for a beta protein (PDB:[1A0S](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1A0S)), and [Rhodopsin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodopsin) for an alpha protein (PDB:[1F88](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1f88)) are two nice structures to look at.

Comment: Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can find examples by using the "drilldown" function at the RCSB PDB homepage:

Click on the number 103921 at the top of the page at http://www.rcsb.org then find the "SCOP Classification" section and then e.g. select "All alpha proteins".